# Rails: How to add "style=" in grouped_select in simple form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, font-awesome

I'd like to add `style=` in a select list as followings;

```
<select style="font-family:'FontAwesome', 'arial'">
```

I use `grouped_select` in simple form.
It would be appreciated if you could give me how to set `style` in a select list.

My view is as below.

```
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :days, @days do |d| %>

        <%= d.simple_fields_for :events do |e| %>

          <span class="form-inline">
            <p>
              <%= e.input :category, 
                :as => :grouped_select, 
                collection: [["Transportation", [["bus", 1], ["taxi", 2], ["train", 3], ["plane", 4] , ["ship", 5], ["bicycle", 6]]],["Eat/Drink", [["meal", 11], ["tea/cafe", 12]]]], 
                :group_method => :last, 
                label: false 
              %>
            </p>
          </span>
          <%= e.input :title, label: false %>

        <% end %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

Although I tried to add `:stlye => "font-family:'FontAwesome', 'arial'"`, it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

```
input_html: { style: "font-family: FontAwesome,arial" }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, @Artem Biserov. Although I tried, it doesn't work. When I check the html, it shows `<select style="font-family:&#39;FontAwesome&#39;,&#39;arial&#39;" `.

Comment: try this
`input_html: { style: "font-family: FontAwesome,arial" }`

Comment: Some context, please?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Artem Biserov. It does't seem to work. But html shows `<select style="font-family: FontAwesome,arial"`. Is this another matter?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @ppperry. `input_html: { style: "font-family: FontAwesome,arial" }` does't seem to work. But html shows `<select style="font-family: FontAwesome,arial"`. Is this another matter?

Comment: Can you confirm that the issue is not with FontAwesome by passing say, background property as described in this answer.